# Deserialization of XML

Tags: c#, xml

Trying to deserialize a XML log file.  And cannot seem to get anything but Error in XML Document(0,0).  I am guessing it has something to do with my class but I cannot seem to find a solution.  I cannot change the XML formatting as this is a log file coming from a server (just simplified)

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<POSLog>
<Transaction>
  <RetailStoreID>1</RetailStoreID>
  <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
  <RetailStoreID>1</RetailStoreID>
  <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
</Transaction>
</POSLog>
```

Class

```
[Serializable()]
public class Transaction
{
    [XmlElement("RetailStoreID")]
    public string RetailStoreID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SequenceNumber")]
    public string SequenceNumber { get; set; }

}

[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("POSLog")]
public class POSLog
{
    [XmlArray("POSLog")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Transaction", typeof(Transaction))]
    public Transaction[] Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize code

```
POSLog poslog = new POSLog();
string path = "POSLog.xml";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(POSLog));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
poslog = (POSLog)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Found fix by switching from StreamReader to FileStream along with changes to the class.  Changing encoding didn't seem to help when using the StreamReader.

Comment: 1) Need Inner exceptions, 2) (offtopic) You use a bit too much attributes.

Comment: Show the stacktrace and in particular the whole exception (the inner exception).

Comment: Since the error is at (0,0), meaning the first character of the first line, I'm guessing it's because your XML file was encoded using UTF with a byte order mark. Try adding an Encoding to your StreamReader.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XmlException while deserializing xml file in UTF-16 encoding format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25298355/xmlexception-while-deserializing-xml-file-in-utf-16-encoding-format)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - The `StreamReader` should detect & consume the BOM automatically.  See the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,181) where `true` is passed for `detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks`.

Comment: I was not able to recreate your issue, plausibly because it's the encoding issue others have mentioned. But I wasn't able to deserialize your XML because according to your attributing, your `Transaction` array is serialized as an element named `POSLog`, within the outer `POSLog` element: `<POSLog><POSLog><Transaction .../><Transaction .../></POSLog></POSLog>`. So that issue will come up when you get the encoding squared away.

Comment: If you do [`File.ReadAllBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) on your XML file, what are the first 20 or so bytes in the file?

Comment: Using the answer below of treating the Transaction as an Element was part of the issue, the main thing that solved my issue was using a FileStream instead of the StreamReader.  Was getting inner exceptions of root element not found.  Switching to the FileStream fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce the problem you are seeing.  However, there is an issue with the `POSLog` class -- it needs to be defined as follows:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("POSLog")]
public class POSLog
{
    [XmlElement("Transaction")]
    public Transaction[] Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

Your XML has a root element `<POSLog>` containing a repeating sequence of `<Transaction>` elements.  [`[XmlElement("Transaction")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) maps the array to just such a one-level repeating sequence.

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SjP5oJ).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Class to the follow above answer

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("POSLog")]
public class POSLog
{
    [XmlElement("Transaction")]
    public Transaction[] Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

Along with Changing the following StreamReader lines

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
poslog = (POSLog)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

To this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
poslog = (POSLog)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

Fixed the issue I was having with the root element and I was able to deserialize the XML.  Thanks to dbc for help in getting me started solving a solution for the first time in a forum!